# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Android resource linking failed

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, build.gradle

I'm running `react-native run-android` and during the build this is the error I get. I'm using the latest version of android studio. A fresh example project I started with `react-native init` works when I run it via android so that tells me I installed android studio correctly, but I'm coming up short on why I can't get through with an existing project.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  /Users/arronlinton/LocalStorage/JAST/JAST/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:69: error: resource mipmap/ic_notif (aka com.jast:mipmap/ic_notif) not found.
  error: failed processing manifest.
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
```

app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jast"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-mail')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-firebase')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    compile project(':react-native-aws')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-mail')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    implementation project(':react-native-fcm')
    implementation project(':react-native-aws')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-mail')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    implementation project(':react-native-fcm')
    implementation project(':react-native-aws')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error it is telling you that you are using the following resource `mipmap/ic_notif` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` but it cannot find it in your `res` folder.

You should check that names and references that you are using for your resources. Specifically the one that you are probably using for notifications.

Also check that your close tags are correct in your `AndroidManifest.xml` as a missed placed `>` can cause errors.