# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Android resource linking failed can longer build RN android version

Tags: gradle, react-native

The android version of my React native app now refuses to build.  I have updated the compiledSKD version to 28 as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250614/aapt-error-resource-androidattr-fontvariationsettings-not-found-and-resource).

This is the error I get when I attempt to build on a physical device:

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
>   > Android resource linking failed   Output:  /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:422:
>   >     error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>   >     /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:422:
>   >     error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.   error: failed
>   >     linking references.
>   >      Command: /Users/someguy/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.5.0-alpha03-5252756-osx.jar/d3ea99fc2d1356bcc9bc022a544dfd8b/aapt2-3.5.0-alpha03-5252756-osx/aapt2
>   >     link -I\
>   >           /Users/someguy/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar\
>   >           --manifest\
>   >           /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
>   >           -o\
>   >           /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
>   >           -R\
>   >           @/Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
>   >           --auto-add-overlay\
>   >           --java\
>   >           /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
>   >           --proguard-main-dex\
>   >           /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules/debug/processDebugResources/manifest_keep.txt\
>   >           --custom-package\
>   >           com.someapp\
>   >           -0\
>   >           apk\
>   >           --output-text-symbols\
>   >           /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
>   >           --no-version-vectors   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-alpha03-5252756-osx Daemon #0   Output: 
>   >     /Users/someguy/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/drawee-1.3.0.aar/cdd2e6e5cf23d268c647bf7bca6ef749/res/values/values.xml:3:5-53:675:
>   >     AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>   >          /Users/someguy/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/drawee-1.3.0.aar/cdd2e6e5cf23d268c647bf7bca6ef749/res/values/values.xml:3:5-53:675:
>   >     AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>   >          error: failed linking references.   Command: /Users/someguy/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.5.0-alpha03-5252756-osx.jar/d3ea99fc2d1356bcc9bc022a544dfd8b/aapt2-3.5.0-alpha03-5252756-osx/aapt2
>   >     link -I\
>   >           /Users/someguy/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar\
>   >           --manifest\
>   >           /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
>   >           -o\
>   >           /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
>   >           -R\
>   >           @/Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
>   >           --auto-add-overlay\
>   >           --java\
>   >           /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
>   >           --proguard-main-dex\
>   >           /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules/debug/processDebugResources/manifest_keep.txt\
>   >           --custom-package\
>   >           com.someapp\
>   >           -0\
>   >           apk\
>   >           --output-text-symbols\
>   >           /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
>   >           --no-version-vectors   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-alpha03-5252756-osx Daemon #0
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 5s 133 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 131 up-to-date

I've also double checked my AndroidManifest.xml file to see if I have any hanging brackets as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501531/execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources-android-resource-linki)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the bundle command?

```
sudo react-native bundle --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --dev false --reset-cache --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

And close the existing packager and re-open packager.

Comment: I just ran it. same error message.  Also, when I tried running `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res` I get an error `EACCES: permission denied, open 'android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle`

Comment: Can you see the following folder in android path? 
android/app/src/main/assets
If no, run this command mkdir android/app/src/main/assets. Then try the above bundle command. Use 'sudo' before command.
And you still have issue, try the following command
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Comment: yep..it's there and there are two files and 1 folder.  The folder is named Fonts and the files are index.android.bundle and index.android.bundle.meta

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding `androidXCore="1.6.0"` in `myApp/android/build.gradle` to look like this

```
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        androidXCore="1.6.0"
```